# Building the platform code with nant and VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nant, cruisecontrol

I'm using the latest nightly build, VS2008 prof trial and .NET 3.5 and
I'm getting this error

"Solution format of file 'C:\test\Project\src\project.sln' is not
supported."

Any Solution to overcome from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know from what you posted if this will work, but if you're trying to run the solution using a the Nant Msbuild task, you might be able to get away with substituting that for a an `exec` task that calls the most recent version of msbuild as an executable. For example:

```
<exec program="msbuild.exe" 
      basedir="C:\windows\microsoft.net\Framework\v3.5\" 
      commandline="C:\test\Project\src\project.sln"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

[NAnt and VS2008 (.NET 3.5) - Solution format of file Solution.sln is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327722/nant-and-vs2008-net-35-solution-format-of-file-solutionsln-is-not-supported)

perhaps this?

http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2007/11/28/upgrade-nant-for-use-with-vs2008-solutions-and-net-3-5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Exec approach just chain them together so that you get all your solutions in the order you need like so:

```
<exec program="msbuild.exe"       basedir="C:\windows\microsoft.net\Framework\v3.5\"       commandline="C:\test\Project\src\project1.sln"/>
```

On a side note based on your first message it sounds like you were trying to use the solution task which currently only supports up to vs2005 as far as I'm aware (could be wrong).

The other alternative is to do something like what a lot of open source projects do (check out the castle project http://castleproject.org) where you have multiple build files 1 per project, a common file, and a master file which allows you to control all the build orders and specifics around each and every project file if you wanted to.

This is how we do it at my place of work.

Hope that helps.