# Continuous Integration Fix for NAnt 0.86 Beta 1 with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have been trying to use the latest NAnt (0.86 Beta 1) for a few weeks now in
several .NET 3.0/3.5 projects as using multiple .sln solution files to build the platform code on my build server but alws ran to error and having this problem :

BUILD FAILED
            Solution format of file 'C:***\Platform.sln' is not supported.
Nested build failed.

PS; To clear more picture here i m trying to use Nant with 2008 multiple *sln (solution) files. 
Intalled Soft on my build server:
VS2008
Nant 0.86 beta1 / nant-0.86-nightly-2009-01-11
Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A
CruisControl version : 1.4.0.3524

Tried every possible scenario; including
I then installed Visual Studio 2008 and in so doing, installed SDK
Version 6.0A.  Once I did this, Nant 0.86 began to work with .NET 3.5.
I adjusted the  tag as follows:

. . .

Should I wait for the fix thill 0.86-beta2 (TBD) release with these fixes, which is also not sure as far as i know from here. any updates for it?

Any over come from this sitauation : Thanks In advance
N@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the **solution** task, it is not supported for anything newer than VS2003. The following question may help with the problem you're seeing:

[NAnt and VS2008 (.NET 3.5) - Solution format of file Solution.sln is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327722/nant-and-vs2008-net-3-5-solution-format-of-file-solution-sln-is-not-supporte)

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but that is it is not supported for anything NEWER that VS2003!

Comment: Woops. I updated the answer. That's definitely what I meant to say. Thanks! :)